# BeautifulSoup with XML fails to parse full unicode strings

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml, python-unicode

**Edited.** I am using BeautifulSoup with lxml to parse XML documents from an external source.  Bizarrely, on some documents, the parser appears to give up in the middle of the text and cut the document short.

I have whittled this down to a precise test case:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
xml = "<ElementA><ElementB>Before bad character XX\n\x80 BAD\nAfter bad character</ElementB><ElementC>In element C</ElementC></ElementA>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml,"xml")
soup
```

Gives incorrect output of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ElementA><ElementB/></ElementA>
```

But if I change just one thing and remove a single character 'X':

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
xml = "<ElementA><ElementB>Before bad character X\n\x80 BAD\nAfter bad character</ElementB><ElementC>In element C</ElementC></ElementA>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml,"xml")
soup
```

Then I get the more complete output of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ElementA><ElementB>Before bad character X
 BAD
After bad character</ElementB><ElementC>In element C</ElementC></ElementA>
```

What is going on?  I am using BeautifulSoup 4.3.2 and LXML 3.4.4 on Python 3.4.3, OSX.

I have so far managed to work around the problem by passing the XML strings through `UnicodeDammit.detwingle()` prior to parsing, but I would be more reassured if I could understand what was going on and how a single additional character can have such a damaging effect on the document.

**Edit.**  Using tools like `detwingle` or `ftfy` no longer works.  Here is an alternative test case, with correct encoding, which on my machine does not get parsed correctly by bs4 / lxml:

```
xml = "<ElementA><ElementB>Before bad character XX\n• BAD\nAfter bad character</ElementB><ElementC>In element C</ElementC></ElementA>"
```

Same problem occurs as above.
Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the best solution, but this is what I do when scraping non-ascii sites. And it works perfect everytime.

Change the default encoding to the same as of the website. In your case `utf-8`

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

so to print/save or parse any non-ascii character you simply do,

```
print 'non-ascii character'.encode('utf-8','ignore') # Replace your text or variable instead of 'non-ascii character'
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Hi, thanks.  It helps a little.  It strips out the bad characters so that bs4 / lxml does not trip up.  Actually, passing it through `detwingle()` or `ftfy.fix_encoding()` is slightly better, because they actually preserve the intended characters rather than stripping them.

My real concern is actually why is the content getting truncated in the first place?  This happens silently, with no warning, so if it happens near the end of larger text I might miss it.  Any ideas on how to stop this happening altogether, without changing the string?

Comment: Agggh, spoke too soon.  `fix_encoding()` doesn't fix it.  The problem occurs even with _valid_ unicode characters.

Replace above example with:
`xml = "<ElementA><ElementB>Before bad character XX\n• BAD\nAfter bad character</ElementB><ElementC>In element C</ElementC></ElementA>`
}

Bullet point is legitimate: soup parsing still stops short.

Is this just my machine or can anyone else recreate it?

Comment: @cmuk Did you change the default encoding to utf-8?

Comment: Yes, utf-8 was already my default encoding (I am on python 3.4).  However, the `encode()` you suggest actually does the trick.  So `BeautifulSoup(str, 'xml')` (as unicode string) does not work, but `BeautfiulSoup(str.encode(),'xml')` (as byte string) _does_ work.  I'm not sure why that's correct, but it's worked for me perfectly on over 9,000 document, so I'm happy. Thanks!